# Assigning values of a dictionary to text boxes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a data dictionary, which uses an string as an index and a list object for the values as below:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dataDict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

I also have 20 textboxes (TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3 etc..)

How could I assign the values within the List object to the twenty text boxes (assuming there are twenty values held within the list object)?

Comment: Why not have the key be the textbox, rather than a string representing that textbox's name?  Additionally is this winforms, WPF, ASP.NET, or what?

Comment: If you really want to do it in this way, just create a collection of TextBoxes and then using e.g lambda assign the values.

Comment: _" uses an int as an index"_ But your key is a string. What are you storing there?

Comment: @ Tim Schmelter Sorry, you are right, it is a string

Comment: @ IDontKnowPopePersonally Can you provide an example please?

Comment: @user1559618 In general you should include that information in the question, or edit it in if you forget.  This time I have done so for you.

Comment: @user1559618 Look at Tim Schmelter answer, its exactly what i meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to put your TextBoxes in a container control like `Panel`:

```
var allTextBoxes = txtPanel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
foreach(var kv in dataDict)
{
    String index = kv.Key;
    String values = String.Join(",", kv.Value);
    TextBox txt = allTextBoxes.FirstOrDefault(txt => txt.Name == "TextBox" + index);
    if(txt != null)
    {
        txt.Text = values;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that I can not understand the question properly (especially the purpose of having a dictionary), but you may use the following:

```
int i = 1;
List<string> values = dataDict["0"]; // gets the first item from the dictionary
foreach (string data in values)
{
    (this.Controls.Find("Textbox" + i, true)[0] as TextBox).Text = data;
    i++;
}
```